# search and replace strings in a ant file

Tags: ant

Hi i would like to create a ant script to search the occurrence of a string "DeployName" in a rule.template file and replace it with the value specified in a deploy.config file. I am kind of novice or starter in ant.any help is appreciated.
(1) Below is the config file from which the value should be taken

```
<config hosts="machineHP" 
environment="local"
tibantHome="C:/internal/tibant"
libLocation="c:/internal/apps"
configHome="C:/internal/apps/config"
projectVersion="1.0"
>
<machineHP >
    <Trade>
        <DeployName>PostTrade</DeployName>
    <Trade>
</machineHP>
</config>
```

(2) Below is the build.xml file which should call the rule.template file and replace the string DeployName with value from the above config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="candeal" basedir="C:\Documents\Test">
<property name="projname" value="RuleBase" />

<target name="createRuleBase">
    <replace file="C:\Documents\Test\rule.template" token="DeployName"     value="PostTrade" />
</target>
<target name="movefile">
        <copy file="C:\Documents\Test\Rule.template" tofile="C:\Documents\Test\PostTrade.hrb" />
</target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

[XmlProperty](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/xmlproperty.html) is all you need. You will end up replacing that `value="PostTrade"` piece with `value="${config.machineHP.Trade.DeployName}"`.